# Using 3dplot package in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, lyx, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3d plot by adapting the [one from the beamer gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/). I'm using LyX 2.0. I keep getting an error that LyX can't compile the file because it can't find

```
\begin{document}
```

Obviously, you don't put this in the LaTeX preamble in Lyx. My document compiled fine before downloading the .sty file and inserting the following line into the preamble.

```
\usepackage{3dplot}
```

This is my full preamble:

```
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
% or ...

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{} % makes the footer EMPTY
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.52,1,0}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}
     \frametitle{Table of Contents}
     \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
      \end{frame}
}
  \usepackage{3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX      
   installation
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{3dplot}
```

causes no errors and generates the example fine.